# Get outgoing links of an element

Tags: jointjs

I want to get all the outgoing links associated with an element .What is the way to achieve this in jointJs .Actually I have tried something like this but It is giving result for both outgoing and incoming .

```
paper.findViewByModel(start).options.inbound=true;
alert(graph.getConnectedLinks(start));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use

```
var outboundLinks = graph.getConnectedLinks(myElement, { outbound: true })
```

See the JointJS API reference here http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Graph:getConnectedLinks.

Comment: Is there any way I can know about the source and target id of first object from this?

Comment: every link has source and target properties containing the ID of its associated objects: `link.get('source').id`